# Remove tikz borders in standalone figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, border

When creating a simple square with lines, `standalone` adds some white space (borders) because the line width exceeds the `fill` limits.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}

\tikzstyle{linha} = [line width=7pt,MaterialGrey300]


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.append style={text=MaterialGrey300, 
font=\Huge}]
\fill[MaterialGrey800] (0,0) rectangle (20,20);
\draw[linha] (0,0) -- (20,20);
\draw[linha] (0,20) -- (20,0);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps this is a trivial question, but is there a way to remove this white space? I tried adding a page color, which improved the situation a little bit, but then the lines do not "bleed" out of the angles (i.e., there are little colored triangles).

Comment: Standalone isn't adding the borders, tikz is.  Add `\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);` right before `\end{tikzpicture}` to see the bounding box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the corners of the thick line overshoot and increase the bounding box. One way to cure this is to use `\clip`. (Notice that if you tried `\clip[fill=MaterialGrey800] (0,0) rectangle (20,20);`, Ti*k*Z would claim that it is impossible to add extra options to `\clip`, but the example shows that this is not really the case.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}

\tikzset{linha/.style={line width=7pt,MaterialGrey300}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text=MaterialGrey300, 
  font=\Huge},fill=MaterialGrey800]
 \clip[fill] (0,0) rectangle (20,20);
 \draw[linha] (0,0) -- (20,20);
 \draw[linha] (0,20) -- (20,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I replaced the deprecated `\tikzstyle` statement by the corresponding `\tikzset` syntax.